# Creating a duplicate window with parameters C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I'm trying to make my windows forms app create a duplicate window with specific parameters when a `New Window` button is clicked. So Basically, when the button is clicked, it will create a new window that is the same as the before window (Not a popup message box). I have found an easy way of doing this:

```
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
```

This code will create an identical window as the form that is named "Form1". However, I want to pass some information to the next window, Something like this:

```
        Form1 form = new Form1("this window was created by clicking the button");
        form.Show();
```

Then I would need some way of accessing the parameters when the window is created.
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create a constructor, methods, or properties for the form class to pass in any data you want.

Constructor:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string titleText)
    {
        // use the parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that I get an error when I try to put a parameter inside "new Form1()".

Comment: You have to declare a parameter in the constructor for this to work.